# Why is Prisma creating a lot of models?

Tags: javascript, orm, graphql, prisma

So I have this query:

```
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255),
  `description` varchar(1000),
  `studio` varchar(255),
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_looking_for_work` boolean,
  `last_active` timestamp,
  `last_login` timestamp,
  `profile_photo` varchar(2000)
);

CREATE TABLE `availability` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `end_time` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500),
  `user_id` int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `chats` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `initiator_id` int NOT NULL,
  `invited_id` int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chat_id` int NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `offers` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` int,
  `colors` ENUM ('white', 'red'),
  `project_image` varchar(10000),
  `finished_image` varchar(10000),
  `price` int NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500),
  `time_needed` int NOT NULL,
  `is_available` boolean NOT NULL,
  `is_in_portfolio` boolean
);

CREATE TABLE `meetings` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `provider` int NOT NULL,
  `client` int NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `duration` int NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `offer_id` int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000),
  `is_style` boolean NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `tags_to_offers` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `offer_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `tags_to_users` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `offers` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `availability` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `chats` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`initiator_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `chats` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`invited_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`chat_id`) REFERENCES `chats` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tags_to_offers` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `offers` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tags_to_offers` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tags_to_users` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tags_to_users` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `meetings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`provider`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `meetings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`client`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `meetings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `offers` (`id`);

COMMIT;
```

It causes prisma to create this schema

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model availability {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  start_time  DateTime
  end_time    DateTime
  description String?
  user_id     Int
  users       users    @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])

  @@index([user_id], name: "user_id")
}

model chats {
  id                              Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  initiator_id                    Int
  invited_id                      Int
  users_chats_initiator_idTousers users      @relation("chats_initiator_idTousers", fields: [initiator_id], references: [id])
  users_chats_invited_idTousers   users      @relation("chats_invited_idTousers", fields: [invited_id], references: [id])
  messages                        messages[]

  @@index([initiator_id], name: "initiator_id")
  @@index([invited_id], name: "invited_id")
}

model meetings {
  id                             Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  provider                       Int
  client                         Int
  date                           DateTime
  duration                       Int
  description                    String
  offer_id                       Int
  users_meetings_clientTousers   users    @relation("meetings_clientTousers", fields: [client], references: [id])
  offers                         offers   @relation(fields: [offer_id], references: [id])
  users_meetings_providerTousers users    @relation("meetings_providerTousers", fields: [provider], references: [id])

  @@index([client], name: "client")
  @@index([offer_id], name: "offer_id")
  @@index([provider], name: "provider")
}

model messages {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  chat_id       Int
  author_id     Int
  content       String
  creation_date DateTime
  users         users    @relation(fields: [author_id], references: [id])
  chats         chats    @relation(fields: [chat_id], references: [id])

  @@index([author_id], name: "author_id")
  @@index([chat_id], name: "chat_id")
}

model offers {
  id              Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  author_id       Int?
  colors          offers_colors?
  project_image   String?
  finished_image  String?
  price           Int
  description     String?
  time_needed     Int
  is_available    Boolean
  is_in_portfolio Boolean?
  users           users?           @relation(fields: [author_id], references: [id])
  meetings        meetings[]
  tags_to_offers  tags_to_offers[]

  @@index([author_id], name: "author_id")
}

model tags {
  id             Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  tag            String
  description    String?
  is_style       Boolean
  tags_to_offers tags_to_offers[]
  tags_to_users  tags_to_users[]
}

model tags_to_offers {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  offer_id Int
  tag_id   Int
  offers   offers @relation(fields: [offer_id], references: [id])
  tags     tags   @relation(fields: [tag_id], references: [id])

  @@index([offer_id], name: "offer_id")
  @@index([tag_id], name: "tag_id")
}

model tags_to_users {
  id      Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  user_id Int
  tag_id  Int
  tags    tags  @relation(fields: [tag_id], references: [id])
  users   users @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])

  @@index([tag_id], name: "tag_id")
  @@index([user_id], name: "user_id")
}

model users {
  id                                Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                              String
  registration_date                 DateTime
  address                           String?
  description                       String?
  studio                            String?
  email                             String
  password                          String
  is_looking_for_work               Boolean?
  last_active                       DateTime?
  last_login                        DateTime?
  profile_photo                     String?
  availability                      availability[]
  chats_chats_initiator_idTousers   chats[]         @relation("chats_initiator_idTousers")
  chats_chats_invited_idTousers     chats[]         @relation("chats_invited_idTousers")
  meetings_meetings_clientTousers   meetings[]      @relation("meetings_clientTousers")
  meetings_meetings_providerTousers meetings[]      @relation("meetings_providerTousers")
  messages                          messages[]
  offers                            offers[]
  tags_to_users                     tags_to_users[]
}

enum offers_colors {
  white
  red
}
```

Which, is not what I was going for. I wanted something like this (GraphQL types):

```
type User {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    registration_date: String!
    address: String
    description: String
    studio: String
    email: String!
    password: String!
    is_looking_for_work: Boolean
    last_active: String
    last_login: String
    profile_photo: String
    availability: [Availability]
    chats: [Chat]
    meetings: [Meeting]
    tags: [Tag]
}
type Offer {
    id: Int!
    author_id: Int!
    colors: String
    project_image: String!
    finished_image: String
    price: Int!
    description: String
    time_needed: Int!
    is_available: Boolean!
    is_in_portfolio: Boolean
    tags: [Tag]
}
type Availability {
    id: Int!
    start_time: String!
    end_time: String!
    description: String
    user_id: Int!
}
type Chat {
    id: Int!
    initiator_id: Int!
    invited_id: Int!
    messages: [Message]
}
type Message {
    id: Int!
    chat_id: Int!
    author_id: Int!
    content: Int!
    creation_date: Int!
}
type Meeting {
    id: Int!
    providerId: Int!
    clientId: Int!
    date: String!
    duration: Int!
    description: String!
    offer_id: Int!
}
type Tag {
    id: Int!
    tag: String!
    description: String
    is_style: Boolean!
}
```

For example let's look at user for simplicity:

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255),
  `description` varchar(1000),
  `studio` varchar(255),
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_looking_for_work` boolean,
  `last_active` timestamp,
  `last_login` timestamp,
  `profile_photo` varchar(2000)
);
```

Prisma

```
model users {
  id                                Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                              String
  registration_date                 DateTime
  address                           String?
  description                       String?
  studio                            String?
  email                             String
  password                          String
  is_looking_for_work               Boolean?
  last_active                       DateTime?
  last_login                        DateTime?
  profile_photo                     String?
  availability                      availability[]
  chats_chats_initiator_idTousers   chats[]         @relation("chats_initiator_idTousers")
  chats_chats_invited_idTousers     chats[]         @relation("chats_invited_idTousers")
  meetings_meetings_clientTousers   meetings[]      @relation("meetings_clientTousers")
  meetings_meetings_providerTousers meetings[]      @relation("meetings_providerTousers")
  // the 4 above: Why are they not in objects?
  messages                          messages[]
  offers                            offers[]
  tags_to_users                     tags_to_users[]
}
```

What I was hoping for

```
type User {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    registration_date: String!
    address: String
    description: String
    studio: String
    email: String!
    password: String!
    is_looking_for_work: Boolean
    last_active: String
    last_login: String
    profile_photo: String
    availability: [Availability]
    chats: [Chat] 
    meetings: [Meeting]
    // meeting and chats. Why are they not like this?
    tags: [Tag]
}
```

And as you can see

```
  chats_chats_initiator_idTousers   chats[]         @relation("chats_initiator_idTousers")
  chats_chats_invited_idTousers     chats[]         @relation("chats_invited_idTousers")
  meetings_meetings_clientTousers   meetings[]      @relation("meetings_clientTousers")
  meetings_meetings_providerTousers meetings[]      @relation("meetings_providerTousers")
```

This is how prisma made the chats and meethings. Also it added objects. But why did it add the 4 above?

What did I mess up in my schema? Or can I create a db schema from my graphql types?

Comment: Hey Alex, one quick question: Do you want to use Prisma 1 or Prisma 2? The actual output uses Prisma 2's model language (using the `model` keyword), but what you are hoping for uses GraphQL SDL which was used in Prisma 1. Could you clarify which version you're intending to use here?

Comment: I was using `prisma/cli`. So not sure what it does in the background. I'm very new to this

Comment: So, one thing I can tell you that Prisma always requires two relation fields for each relation. A relation is specified by a foreign key, so per foreign key in your DB you'll get two relation fields in the Prisma schema on the respective models. I'd recommend to read the [Relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations) page in the docs for a bit more info on this :)

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks!